# Get Message body at login xmpp in android

Tags: android, xmpp

How to get Message body at login xmpp in android?

I want to get offline message at login time in xmpp.

Any one have idea about. Any help would appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got offline message at login in xmpp server.

```
 connection.connect();
        connection.login(username, password);
        connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                final Message message = (Message) packet;
                if (message.getBody() != null) {
                    String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message
                            .getFrom());
                    Log.i("XMPPClient", "Got text [" + message.getBody()
                            + "] from [" + fromName + "]");     


                            }
                        }
                    }, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your server.  [XEP-0160](http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0160.html) recommends that the server store offline messages, and deliver them whenever the recipient sends presence with non-negative priority.  If that's not what you're seeing, the first place to look is probably the server configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In Xmpp Server setting server store offline messages, is already given. Now I have implemented addPackageLister just after login, now i am able to fetch offline messages.